# How to translate 'Market Access' into Chinese?

Tags: translation, word-requests

How to translate 'Market Access','Consumer Market Access' and 'Firm Market Access'?

Definition
 - 'Market Access' is the extent concept. Under this concept, 'Consumer Market Access' means that the extent of the market the consumer can access.
Similarly, 'Firm market access' refers to the extent concept.

Hope someone can help me to improve the translation.

市场进入，市场获得，市场邻进，市场获取，which one should I choose?

If add "消费者" or "企业" before it, which one is the best?

Comment: jukuu has 100 example sentences for "market access"; 市场准入

Comment: In fact jukuu only has 68 example sentences for "market access", however all of these have 市场准入 except for 61 市场自由准入 (free m a),66, 68 with 市场的准入

Answer (score 1):

"MARKET ACCESS" means "市场准入" in Chinese.

eg.
However, a loosening of market access rules is expected to occur in the coming years.
然而, 在未来几年里,市场准入规则预计将不断放宽.

Answer (score 0):

> http://www.zdic.net/c/8/152/337518.htm
>
> ◎ **门径** /**門徑** ménjìng
>   [access] 門前的小路 (the path lead to the door)

市场门径 (Market Access)

消费者市场门径 (Consumer Market Access)

企业市场门径 (Firm Market Access)

Comment: I think 'consumer market access' refers to a company's ability to access the consumer market, not the access of the consumers to a given market.

Comment: *'consumer market access' refers to a company's ability to access the consumer market* -- 消费者市场门径 means just that: "消费者市场"=consumer market , 门径=access(to)

Comment: 'consumer market access' refers to the extent of market that the consumer can access.@Gangosa

Comment: The way I look at (but I am not an economist) a consumer always has access to the market: just buy something, whereas a company may not, for whatever reason, be able to penetrate the consumer market.

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, the author examined the relationship between specific commitments and **market access**.

在明确具体承诺的解释规则之后, 笔者进而分析了具体承诺与**市场准入**的关系.

consumer market access 消费市场准入

What to you mean by 'firm market access'? Better if you write a sentence!

The company's access to the Chinese market is very limited.
该公司对中国市场的渗透是非常有限的.

Maybe something like that?

Comment: 准入= enter
渗透= penetration,

Answer (score 0):

According to Chinese Wiki MBA (http://wiki.mbalib.com/wiki/%E5%B8%82%E5%9C%BA%E5%87%86%E5%85%A5),

market access -> 市場準入 (T) / 市场准入 (S)

Using the basis of market access, a logical translation for these two would be

a consumer market access -> 消费者市场准入
and a firm market access -> 企业市场准入

Interestingly enough, there is no such word as "consumer market access" and "firm market access" that is commonly used. (Quick google search had 0 results for firm market access and consumer market access, but had results for **firm behavior** and market access.

I propose the following. Using the definition of market access from business dictionary, http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/market-access.html,
"Openness of a country's markets to foreign goods and services. Market access reflects the government's economic policies regarding import substitution and free competition." Market access would be a **reflection** of a **government's policies** regarding **access to markets**.

There could be some tweeks that can be made to reflect your definition of consumer market access -> Market Access for Consumers , of course this would also change its definition into something like, the consumer's behavior that reflects the government's economic policies regarding access to markets. The same can be said for firm.

Comment: Consumer behavior according to market access -> 消费者对于市场准入 , Firm behavior according to market access -> 企业对于市场准入, both translations (by me) leave out behavior (行為), it feels weird and I believe the meaning is kept even without mentioning behavior

Comment: After looking at Chinese Wiki MBA (http://wiki.mbalib.com/wiki/%E5%B8%82%E5%9C%BA%E5%87%86%E5%85%A5), they also use terms such as 其他國家市場準入 and 我國市場準入, this makes it feel much safer to just use 消费者市场准入 and 企业市场准入